# Get the start and end time of the 2 hour even segment that current time lies on in Javascript/Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, datetime, rounding

I need to find the 2 even hour segment that current time lies on.
If current time is 07:10:00 then the segment would be 06:00:00 to 08:00:00.

Time segment is always 2 hours and from even hour to even hour.

I tried manually to round off the current time and finding the nearest two even numbers for the hour. But having problems in edge cases.

Is there a proper way to do this may be using some Javascript/JQuery date functions?

Comment: If you're having problems with edge cases then it's probably helpful to tell us what those problem edge cases are.

Comment: jQuery does not have any date functions.

Answer (score 3):

To achieve this you can take the hour from the `Date()` and then round it down to the nearest even hour. Try this:

```js
var date = new Date(); // = now
var startHour = 2 * Math.floor(date.getHours() / 2);
var endHour = startHour + 2;

console.log(startHour);
console.log(endHour);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
var currentHour = (new Date()).getHours();
var startHour = currentHour - currentHour % 2;  // it will subtract 1 for odd hours
var endHour = startHour + 2;

var segmentStart = (startHour<10?"0":"") + startHour + ":00:00";
var segmentEnd = (endHour<10?"0":"") + endHour + ":00:00";
```